# Android Which is the best way to convert text to a bitmap including typeface, color and size?

Tags: android, string, image, text, bitmap

I'm trying to convert a String to a bitmap and finally I found a solution:

```
public static Bitmap textToBitmap(Context c, String text, String typeface, int size, int color){



    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(size);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setSubpixelText(true);
    paint.setColor(color);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),typeface);
    paint.setTypeface(tf);
    int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.5f); // round
    float baseline = (int) (paint.ascent()*(0.80f) + 0.5f);
    int height = (int) (paint.descent()*(0.5f) - paint.ascent()*(0.70f) + 0.5f);
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    int y = (int) (baseline*(-1));
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, y, paint);


    return image;

}
```

My problem is that this solution doesn't work very well for all screens (because width and height are not correct) and is a bit coarse.

Is there a best code to do this?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting sizes in pixels set them in dips and then convert to pixels. Like this

```
    final float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    final float textSizeDips = 10f;
    final float textSizePixels = Math.round(textSizeDips * density);

    paint.setTextSize(textSizePixels);
```

This will fix problem with different text size on different screens.

Comment: Many thanks. It's a great solution but my problem is to find a best way to set width and height in: Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);